# Замена содержимого через Browser history API

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api, history-api

Есть код (снизу). Его задача менять содержимое (подгружая его с файла) при нажатии на кнопку.

Все работает, но поступила задача сделать тоже самое но через Browser history API.

Просто не могу въехать как это сделать...

**Код:**

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; Charset=UTF-8">   
</head>  
  <body> 
    <form>  
        <input onclick="showContent('/content/div-first.html')" type="button" value="Страница 1">  
        <input onclick="showContent('/content/div-second.html')" type="button" value="Страница 2">  
    </form>  

    <div id="contentBody">  
    </div>  

    <div id="loading" style="display: none">  
    Идет загрузка...  
    </div>  
      <script>
    function showContent(link) {
  var cont = document.getElementById('contentBody');
  var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
  var http = createRequestObject();

  cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;

  if (http) {
    http.open('get', link);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (http.readyState == 4) {
        cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;
      }
    }
    http.send(null);
  } else {
    document.location = link;
  }
}

function createRequestObject() {
  try {
    return new XMLHttpRequest()
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
      } catch (e) {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
      </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Еще советую посмотреть в сторону https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: @Microfed Да это круто, но мне нельзя использовать подобное. Необходимо нативное решение...